# onKeyDown or onBackPressed in a parent activity

Tags: android, tabactivity

I have a [TabActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html) that shows other [Activities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) as the content based on which tab is selected. What I want to do is from the 'parent' Activity try to capture the back key press, but neither [onKeyDown()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) nor [onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) ever get called in the parent... it's being handled by the 'child' Activities. Is there any way to have it pass up to the 'parent' Activity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just using, from within the child Activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed () {
    this.getParent().onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: I don't like having to call it from each child, but this works out fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could set up a communication procedure between the TabActivity and his childs.

I created a static [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) in the TabActivity which was initialized in the onCreate of the TabActivity.

Then i created a static getHandler() method (in the TabActivity ).

Now a snippet to achieve your question for your childs would be:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed () {
    MyTabActivity.getHandler().sendEmptyMessage(MyTabActivity.BACK_PRESSED);
}
```

Comment: @ShadowCloud solution is suitable as well.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same problem as well. I sovled it this way:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
{
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        //things u want to do when back key pressed
    }    
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```